# Visual Studio 2022 (.Net 6) with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,Core (2.18.3 or higher) getting ORA-12607: TNS: Connect timeout occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, oracle-manageddataaccess

Problem:
I am trying to use the Oracle.ManagedDataAccessCore (2.18.3 or higher) version to access and to query the Oracle Database but the program kept throwing ORA-12607: TNS: Connect timeout occurred when I tried to run a query using the following codes below.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EqpStateDto>>> GetEqpState() 
        {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM MAC_STATE";

            using (var connection = _dapperContext.CreateConnection())
            {
                var eqpStates = await connection.QueryAsync<EqpStateDto>(query);
                return Ok(eqpStates.ToList());
            }
        }
```

Background:
I've tried using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccessCore 2.12.0-beta2 version and it is WORKING. Somehow it is not working if I were to use the 2.18.3 version or higher.

I have tried setting the pooling to false ("Pooling=false") and increased the connection timeout ("Connection Timeout=60") but it doesn't resolve the issue.

Is there any configuration that I need to include in order for it to work?